# How to concatenate data from multiple vertical cells to one cell in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe something like this

[image]

I want to combine row 0 to row 5 so that the dataframe should look like this

[image: Formatted DF]

Please find the unformatted DF below

```
{0: {0: 'Budget allocation for 1998-2019 financial years',
  1: 'In million',
  2: 'USD',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: 'Atyrau',
  7: 'Mangistau',
  8: 'Total'},
 1: {0: '',
  1: 'ITD VOWD',
  2: 'Dec',
  3: '',
  4: '2018',
  5: '',
  6: '318.5',
  7: '302.3',
  8: '620.8'},
 2: {0: '',
  1: 'YTD VOWD',
  2: 'February',
  3: '',
  4: '2019',
  5: 'Incl. VAT',
  6: '5.1',
  7: '2.0',
  8: '7.2'},
 3: {0: '',
  1: 'ITD VOWD',
  2: 'February',
  3: '',
  4: '2019',
  5: '[A]',
  6: '323.6',
  7: '304.3',
  8: '628.0'},
 4: {0: '',
  1: 'PSA obligation',
  2: 'as of Feb` 2019',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '[B]',
  6: '362.6',
  7: '362.6',
  8: '725.3'},
 5: {0: '',
  1: 'Existing',
  2: 'commitments',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '[C]',
  6: '43.9',
  7: '51.9',
  8: '95.8'},
 6: {0: '',
  1: 'Available',
  2: 'approved',
  3: 'budget',
  4: '[B-A-C]',
  5: 'Incl. VAT',
  6: '-5',
  7: '6',
  8: '2'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
## concat every column for 5 rows into a pd.Series
df = df.iloc[0:6, :].apply(' '.join) 

## convert Series to dataframe and Transpose it
df = pd.DataFrame(df).T
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank, For the logic. I modified a bit and achieved the output . Appreciate ur assistance although

df1[0:7] = df1.iloc[0:6, :].apply(' '.join)
df1.drop_duplicates(keep = 'first', inplace = True)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)